# Issue with HttpWebRequest Google.com

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

I have a C# application that searches on Google. After a few hits, I see the captcha message.

To solve this, I open Internet Explorer, go to the same page, and I'm presented with the captcha as well. I complete that and then, its all good; search results are shown.

But in my c# application when I hit the same URL, I still see the captcha. Why is that, and how could I bypass it? I am confused as I've completed the captcha (using IE), so why do I see it again on next hit in c# but not from the browser!

I just need to be pointed in the right direction , or some ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Isn't it clear? Google doesn't want you to scrape that page. Use Search API's instead.

Comment: @I4V i know , it not that i want to scrap it it's why it shows captcha on the app but not on webpage when i have entered captcha

Comment: @Must me on to something succeeded once :| after captcha lets see if it continues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of how Google does it, but I've seen websites which track how often you use them based on:

1. IP Address
2. User-Agent String
3. Cookies

You can spoof number 2 so its the same as in Internet Explorer, just in case its through that.

Number 3 is easy to check I suppose, and you can transmit the cookie if there is one.

Comment: 1- Same , as on same pc , 2 is same aswell , 3 must be too as i just open IE and enter that url and search same as in HTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Google wants to prevent other people to send requests by their own applications, there is no advertise , ... . And maybe this is attack, You've two options : 1. Your application should act as the way as the browser acts , for example modifying User-Agent and cookies. 2. Contact google to provide you a API. I'm sure Google provides API for this reason , but I've no more details information.